# Windows 7 snapping incorrectly

Tags: windows-7

I am using two monitors (laptop + DP>VGA).

Most of snaps would not go entirely fullscreen for some reason.

See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does the same issue occur when you maximise?

Comment: No, maximise works fine.

Comment: Does this issue occur with Windows Explorer?

Comment: Yes it does. Happens with all applications.